# Server request android location

Tags: android, mobile, push-notification, location, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way for a server to request for the location of all of the users of the android app at once? I am new to android development and I am not sure if this is possible. I know that if the app needs the users current location then within the application a function can be called to get the coordinates but is it possible for a server to request them all?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for you to request location information for all app users from a server. It would be possible to collect location information at set intervals and store that information on your server. This can be done using the setInterval() method of LocationRequest.